# QTextEdit set cursor position at any point

Tags: qt, qt5, qtextedit

I'm trying to positioning text that i received from server (with ANSI escape sequence). Sequence
`\1xB[x;yH` gives me X and Y (col and row) coordinates for output the next data.

The problem is QTextCursor moving only relative to existing text in widget, so i can't set position at any point in QTextEdit.

How can I achieve this? Or maybe there is another widget that fits better for my purpose?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to use QTextEdit? And if you need to position text cursor to some location, why don't you add some newlines and spaces so that you can reach the row and line you need?

Comment: I thought about filling QTextEdit with spaces entirely, so i could use ```QTextCursor::movePosition``` and just replace spaces with my data, but I'm new in Qt and don't know if it's a good solution.
I chose QTextEdit because it's supports rich text, i need it.  
P.S. Let's assume that i have an empty widget and I want just set cursor at any position of it and type text. This is what i want to achieve. 

Thank you.